# Mixed type in suffix in pd.wide_to_long

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pd.wide_to_long but it returns to an empty dataframe. Having checked online, I thought it could be an issue of suffix. It is a combination of numbers and letters. Below is a sample code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A 1970-01 USD" : {0 : 2.5, 1 : 1.2, 2 : .7},
                   "A 1980-01 USD" : {0 : 3.2, 1 : 1.3, 2 : .1},
                   "X"     : dict(zip(range(3), np.random.randn(3)))})
df["id"] = df.index
```

Below are what I tried. All of them return to an empty dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A "], i="id", j="year", suffix='\w')
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A "], i="id", j="year", suffix='\d')
df_test = pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A "], i="id", j="year", suffix='\\w+d+')
```

The desired outcome is something like this:

```
id  year           A    X
0   1970-01 USD 2.5 -1.59
1   1970-01 USD 1.2 -0.625
2   1970-01 USD 0.7 -0.251
0   1980-01 USD 3.2 -1.59
1   1980-01 USD 1.3 -0.625
2   1980-01 USD 0.1 -0.251
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: could you specify your desired outcome please?

Comment: Added the desired outcome. Thanks.